# "Usage: PdfContentReaderTool <pdf file> [<output file>|stdout] [<page num>]" out of nowhere

Tags: java, pdf, jar, itext, libraries

When I run my Java project in the output the text: Usage:  PdfContentReaderTool  [|stdout] []
 is displayed. And it happens even if there is not a single thing in my main method. I have heard that it is connected to iText jars. In my project Referenced Libraries project I use itextpdf-5.4.1.jar. Why is that happening?

Comment: How do you run your Java project? How did you build its jar file (assuming you have a jar file and you're trying to run it)?

Comment: How does you java project looks like? Are you sure that you are starting your main class or is it autodiscovered by a build tool?

Comment: I run it in Eclipse.

Comment: That's quite a vague description. My guess is that you're executing a run configuration (or whatever eclipse calls them) where the configured main class is  PdfContentReaderTool, and not your desired main class.